# What is this notation called?

Tags: piano

[image: Example of notation in question used]

(piano)
I am currently working on a piece that heavily uses this notation to indicate jumping back and forth between notes, usually in a triad of some sort.
What is the name of this notation and (not necessary) could you recommend any exercises to get better at doing them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called *tremolo*, but it's not necessary to write that word in the score - the beamlets are well-known enough to get the meaning across.